# RewriteRule doesn't retrieve characters generated by php function

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a php script which takes file url as argument and sends back the file content.
I generate the urls dynamically :

```
<img src="get/<?php echo get_file_path_by_ID($album['IDCover']); ?>" />
```

which will generate a url like this :

```
<img src="get/16volt\Primal\Folder.jpg">
```

The RewriteRule is :

```
RewriteRule ^get/(.+) get.php?path=$1 [L]
```

The problem is that the string generated by PHP is always ignored so the $1 is always empty.
I can see in the console that the URL called is :

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://localhost:8080/mediatheque3/get/16volt%5CPrimal%5CFolder.jpg"

But on my get.php file the `$_GET['path']` is always empty.

If I change the src like :

```
<img src="get/<?php echo 'plop'.get_file_path_by_ID($album['IDCover']); ?>" />
```

I will only get "**plop**" in the `$_GET['path']`.

Why does the src seems correct but the `$_GET['path']` isn't retrieved by apache ?

Comment: So from your question - the url does not match because your rule explicitly states it must start with `get` which is not true since it starts with `mediatheque3`

Comment: Nope, I have a RewriteBase rule for that and the url matches when I add static text right after the "get/"

Comment: then check what's in `$album['IDCover']` and the output of the corresponding function.

Comment: The output is right since the url is correct. If I echo the output somewhere else I still have "16volt\Primal\Folder.jpg" which is the right string. But when that URL is called the string's part returned by the function is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem comes from the backslashes, I noticed that by trying with static in-html url with backslashes which doesn't work either, and replaced it by slashes. Now the $_GET['path'] is filled with the information.
Anyway thanks for your help.